# Obtener datos de una tabla, transact sql

Tags: sql

necesito su ayuda con este problema que me surgio al tratar de obtener ciertos datos de una tabla.
Sucede que tengo una tabla que almacena los numeros de telefono de los clientes que llaman para realizar una determinada compra, la compra queda relacionada directamente con el cliente, el numero de telefono y la hora en que llamo.
Lo que quiero es obtener solo los datos de las llamadas que terminaron en una venta. EJ:

```
SELECT distinct lla.año_periodo,
                lla.mes_periodo,
                lla.dFecha,
                lla.T_hora,
                lla.dFechaHora,
                lla.dFin,
                lla.tiempo as tiempo_segundos,
                lla.sNumeroTelefono,
                num.descripcion as Cliente_llamada,
                cli.Cod_Cliente as cod_cliente_llamada,
                lla.tipo,
                lla.Agente as cod_ejecutiva,
                bor.nom_ejecutiva,
                new.Nom_Cliente as Cliente_venta,
                new.cod_cliente as cod_cliente_venta,
                new.cod_vendedora,
                new.nom_vendedora,
                new.Cod_Promotora,
                new.Nom_Promotora,
                new.val_precio_pesos_sum
        
FROM (#LLAMADAS LLA
left JOIN #BORRADOR_EJECUTIVA BOR
on bor.cod_ejecutiva = lla.Agente
left join #NUMEROS_CLIENTES num
on lla.sNumeroTelefono = num.num_cliente
left join #NUEVA_TABLA new
on bor.nom_ejecutiva = new.nom_vendedora
and num.descripcion = new.Nom_Cliente
and lla.T_hora = new.T_hora
and lla.dFecha = new.regis_Fecha
left join Analisis.dbo.CLIENTES cli
)where tiempo > 30

order by dFechaHora
```

esta query genera algo así:

```
hora          Numero    Cliente     Venta
-------------------------------------------
18:56:02    87736452    camilo      NULL
19:32:24    67890247    alfaro      $12000
19:09:37    93487201    jorge       $789
20:23:00    65578909    cristian    NULL
20:23:00    65578909    cristian    $456
20:23:00    65578909    cristian    NULL
22:56:48    81940592    alvaro      NULL
```

Lo que necesito es que me genere la tabla pero solo con los datos de cristian que tengan una venta.

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: talves te falte una tabla detalle. el detalle siendo la factura, y solo almacenara las ventas realizadas.

Answer (score 0):

No estoy seguro de que te haya entendido a la perfección pero me parece que simplemente necesitas otra condición, así:

```
SELECT distinct lla.año_periodo,
                lla.mes_periodo,
                lla.dFecha,
                lla.T_hora,
                lla.dFechaHora,
                lla.dFin,
                lla.tiempo as tiempo_segundos,
                lla.sNumeroTelefono,
                num.descripcion as Cliente_llamada,
                cli.Cod_Cliente as cod_cliente_llamada,
                lla.tipo,
                lla.Agente as cod_ejecutiva,
                bor.nom_ejecutiva,
                new.Nom_Cliente as Cliente_venta,
                new.cod_cliente as cod_cliente_venta,
                new.cod_vendedora,
                new.nom_vendedora,
                new.Cod_Promotora,
                new.Nom_Promotora,
                new.val_precio_pesos_sum

FROM (#LLAMADAS LLA
left JOIN #BORRADOR_EJECUTIVA BOR
on bor.cod_ejecutiva = lla.Agente
left join #NUMEROS_CLIENTES num
on lla.sNumeroTelefono = num.num_cliente
left join #NUEVA_TABLA new
on bor.nom_ejecutiva = new.nom_vendedora
and num.descripcion = new.Nom_Cliente
and lla.T_hora = new.T_hora
and lla.dFecha = new.regis_Fecha
left join Analisis.dbo.CLIENTES cli
)where tiempo > 30
and new.val_precio_pesos_sum is not null

order by dFechaHora
```

Nota la parte que dice `and new.val_precio_pesos_sum is not null` al final, de esta manera estarías descartando todas las llamadas que no terminaron en ventas.

Comment: pero sucede que si me interesa saber las llamadas que no terminaron en ventas, lo que no me gusta es que cristian me repite la hora 3 veces  y en solo una de ellas hizo una venta, entonces en el caso de cristian como me repite 3 veces lo mismo, solo me interesa guardar el que hizo ventas.

Gracias por tu tiempo

Comment: PD: utilize a cristian como ejemplo, por que es el dato que se repetia, pero me interesa sabe los datos de todos, no solo de cristian

Answer (score 0):

Podrías comparar

> and Venta is not null

eso si quisieras excluir todos los nulos, lo que sucede con los left join es que tienden a multiplicar los registros, pero evidentemente una de las tablas contiene más de un registro que  no esta siendo excluido, puede ser la unión por la descripción y el nombre de cliente, tal vez podrías considerar generar claves de acceso únicos para las tablas.

Answer (score 0):

> "Lo que necesito es que me genere la tabla pero solo con los datos de cristian que tengan una venta."

Si quieres que te genere una tabla con lo que mencionas arriba puedes usar :

```
SELECT 
    c1,c2 
INTO 
    #TablaTemporal 
FROM 
    (toda tu consulta) 
where 
    Cliente='cristian' and Venta IS NOT NULL
```

Toda tu respuesta estaria en #TablaTemporal obviamente esta tabla se crea al instante de hacer tu SELECT tal cual tiene las columnas y tipos de datos.

Comment: pero sucede que si me interesa saber las llamadas que no terminaron en ventas, lo que no me gusta es que cristian me repite la hora 3 veces y en solo una de ellas hizo una venta, entonces en el caso de cristian como me repite 3 veces lo mismo, solo me interesa guardar el que hizo ventas, el problema es que el left join me duplica los datos en base a la hora. Si cristian hubiera llamado en una hora diferente y no hubier realizado una compra, igual me interesa tener esa información. Gracias por tu tiempo

Comment: PD: utilize a cristian como ejemplo, por que es el dato que se repetia, pero me interesa sabe los datos de todos, no solo de cristian